# How is the best method to query using $firebaseArray equalTo() array values?

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

Consider I have structured my database like this,

```
users:{
   user1: {
      username: "johndoe"
   },
   user2: {
      username: "foobar"
   }
}

user-timeline: {
   user1: {
      post1: true,
      post2: true,
      post3: true
   },
   user2: {
      post3: true
   }
}

posts: {
   post1:{
      caption: "caption 1",
      author: "user1"
   },
   post2:{
      caption: "caption 2",
      author: "user1"
   },
   post3:{
      caption: "caption 3",
      author: "user2"
   }
}
```

How is the best method to get all post data including the author data for each post that associated to user1's timeline? Since user1 has `post1, post2, and post3` associated in his timeline, so the query expected to fetch data like this:

```
[
  {
    $id: post1,
    caption: "caption 1",
    author:{
      $id: "user1", username: "johndoe"
    }
  },
  {
    $id: post2,
    caption: "caption 2",
    author:{
      $id: "user1", username: "johndoe"
    }
  },
  {
    $id: post3,
    caption: "caption 3",
    author:{
      $id: "user2", username: "foobar"
    }
  }
]
```

I know, currently firebase doesn't support query from multiple values something similar like this:

```
$firebaseArray($firebaseRef.child('posts').equalTo(['post1','post2','post3']));
```

Can someone explain the best method to implement it using AngularFire and keep the data synchronized each time a new post is being added or removed?

Comment: Two years later, and this is still impossible....